# Spring MVC Ajax: Passing Empty Array to Ajax Controller

Tags: java, ajax, spring, spring-mvc

I have the following which works well in receiving a non-empty Array,

```
$.ajax({
  url: "ajaxController",
  dataType: "json",
  type: "get",
  data: {
       'term': request.term,
       'exclude': ["45","66"]
  },
```

Controller (note the `[]` in RequestParam Value -- the result goes in a String[]):

```
public List<KeyValueBean> getChoices(String term, 
                                     @RequestParam(value = "exclude[]") 
                                        String[] exclude)  {
}
```

But if I pass an empty array in the same code, which sometimes happens, it breaks:

```
'exclude': []
```

or alternatively

```
'exclude': JSON.stringify([])
```

Error:

```
org.springframework.web.bind.MissingServletRequestParameterException: Required 
String[] parameter 'exclude[]' is not present
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you pay attention to the error, it says your request parameter `exclude` can not be null. If you need to can send empty array sometimes, you can mark your parameter as optional(not required) in this way:

```
@RequestParam(required = false, value = "exclude[]")
```

Comment: Yes this was the closest solution. But you have one error: You can't use `value="exclude"` Spring requires brackets: `value="exclude[]"`. Once I fixed that, both cases (empty & non-empty) started working. But my question still is, I'm not passing a NULL, I'm passing an empty array. Why is Spring receiving a NULL? That's not what I want to send. If I meant a NULL, I would pass `'exclude': null`.

Comment: This type of error is related to validation. In terms of arrays validation, null and empty array have same concept. I means, there is not any difference if you send null array or empty array! In both cases, you are violating validation rule.

Comment: But the question is why Spring bound `[]` to a NULL. There is a difference in what I passed. I didn't pass `null` I passed a `[]`. Spring could have done the `String[]` binding (Array of Length 0), which is what I was expecting. It's my own decision whether `[]` is valid while NULL is not, they should get separate binding.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is probably because you passed your @RequestParam with `value="exclude[]"` while you are passing the object named as "exclude".

So, it actually should be:

```
public List<KeyValueBean> getChoices(String term, 
                                 @RequestParam(value = "exclude") 
                                    String[] exclude)  {
}
```